# Setting Up Multiple Source Folders in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, image, working-directory

How do you setup multiple source folders in Eclipse?  Here is a sample project:

```
public class Main {

public Main() {
    try {
        String path = "image.jpg";
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Loaded the image!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
}
}
```

I added a source folder by right clicking the project and selecting "New>Source Folder" and put my image into the folder.  The project ran fine.

Then, I added another source folder by right clicking the project and selecting "New>Source Folder" and moved my image to the new folder.  This time, the project threw an IO exception.

I moved the image back to the first folder and ran the project again (both folders still in the project) and the project ran fine.

I created both folders exactly the same way, and I was refreshing the folders in-between image moves, yet it seems the project can only read from the 1st folder.

How do I add another folder so that when I put the image into the 2nd folder the program will run through without an IO exception?

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Source_ is _Allow output folders for source folder_ checked?

Comment: It is was not checked, thanks!

Comment: I thought the reason might be that the checkbox was checked. But using `getResourceAsStream` which uses the class loader it should make no difference whether the compiled `.class` files and the image are located together in one or separate output folders.

Comment: Ohhh yes I see that it still does not work.  I have since gave up and just put the 2nd folder inside the 1st one, and when getting a resource from the 2nd folder I just add a 2ndFolderName\\ before the image name and it works.